# Move sensitive browsing data to an _encrypted_ location

Tags: google-chrome, browser, encryption, windows-11, chromium

Where and exactly what files/directories do Google Chrome/IronSrware save with my sensitive private data?

I want to move them to the encrypted partition E: (Bitlocker(Windows 11/ I use Google account sync - passwords/favorites etc.) via symlink "mklink /D". The encrypted partition is slower, so I want to move only sensitive files and leave the rest of the cache on the C drive (Unencrypted)
in: `*\users\xxx\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default\` :

- Default\Sync Data\\
- Bookmarks\
- History\
- Login Data\
- Login Data For Account\
- Web Data\
- Visited Links\

**What else?**